# How to copy a file and rename it with a random number with js

Tags: javascript, random, numbers, copy

I have a many files and I need to rename them with shuffle numbers.

Here is an example with 50 files (1 to 50) I found this code and I'am able to get the files renamed and put in a new folders ...

BUT some are not copied since their is some numbers that are generated twice.
And if I run the script again and again, I get all my new 50 files but there is some that are duplicated.

```
const fs = require('fs');

for (let i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {

  function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    
    let totalEle = max - min + 1;
    let result = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalEle) + min;
    return result;
  }
  function createArrayOfNumber(start, end) {
    let myArray = [];
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      myArray.push(i);
    }
    return myArray;
  }
  let numbersArray = createArrayOfNumber(1, 50);

    let randomIndex = getRandomNumber(0, numbersArray.length - 1);
    let randomNumber = numbersArray[randomIndex];
    numbersArray.splice(randomIndex, 1);

    fs.copyFile(`old/${i}.json`, `new/${randomNumber}.json`, (err) => {});
}
```

It's my first steps in js, I try to figure it out and I'm not... What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add a start index to [norbot's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70239622/)

```
const fs = require("fs");

const startIndex = 1
const numberOfFiles = 5;

// Create an array containing numbers from 1 to the numberOfFiles defined
let availableNumbers = Array.from({ length: numberOfFiles  }, (v, k) => k + 1);
for (let i = startIndex; i < startIndex + numberOfFiles; i++) {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableNumbers.length);
  let randomNumber = availableNumbers[randomIndex];
  fs.copyFile(`old/${i}.json`, `new/${randomNumber}.json`, (err) => { });
  availableNumbers.splice(randomIndex, 1);
}
```

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for so I made only one modification. So if I take file 21 to 50, they are also renamed 21 to 50.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are defining the functions and `numbersArray` in the loop, so you do it for every iteration, hence the numbers becoming duplicated. (So it's like you didn't remove the number from the `numbersArray`)

Here is a solution that I would use:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const numberOfFiles = 50;

// Create an array containing numbers from 1 to the numberOfFiles defined
let availableNumbers = Array.from({ length: numberOfFiles }, (v, k) => k + 1);
for (let i = 1; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableNumbers.length);
    let randomNumber = availableNumbers[randomIndex];
    fs.copyFile(`old/${i}.json`, `new/${randomNumber}.json`, (err) => { });
    availableNumbers.splice(randomIndex, 1);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!

I work perfectly but if I want to do a partial shuffle,

 for example, only files from #20 to #50 ? I did try to change the number of files to 30 and the i=21 to make it start to 21 instead of 1 and it return to only a few files that are not all higher than 21.

is there a from x to y function we can put in it ?

Comment: Yes. You can modify `let i = 1` to the number you would like to start with.
Also, why is this not the accepted answer? Seems a bit unfair. The currently accepted answer should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I tested and re-wrote your code. There are some things that would help it function as intended.

I moved your functions out of the code to prevent redefining the function each iteration of the loop.

I added an array `alreadyHit` which the function `gerRandomNumber` checks for the number already having been used. If it has already been used then we use some recursive logic to just call the function again. I added a bit of error testing to prevent an infinite loop if there are no more numbers left. Basically, if there are more than 100 attempts to make a random number, we throw an error.

Please ask if you have any questions

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const alreadyHit = [];
function getRandomNumber(min, max, attempts = 0) {
  if (attempts > 100) throw new Error("Not enough numbers probably");
  let totalEle = max - min + 1;
  let result = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalEle) + min;
  if (alreadyHit.includes(result)) return getRandomNumber(min, max, attempts + 1);
  return result;
}

function createArrayOfNumber(start, end) {
  let myArray = [];
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    myArray.push(i);
  }
  return myArray;
}

const numbersArray = createArrayOfNumber(1, 50);
for (let i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
  const randomIndex = getRandomNumber(0, numbersArray.length - 1);
  const randomNumber = numbersArray[randomIndex];
  alreadyHit.push(randomIndex);
  fs.copyFile(`./old/${i}.json`, `./new/${randomNumber}.json`, err => {
    if (err) console.log("Error Found:", err);
  });
}
```

Comment: This work perfectly,

Comment: I can even change the range where I want to use it (20 to 40, or 30 to 50,...)

Now I have an other question, 
Once the new file is created, I need to update 2 values inside the file that refer to the file number.

So for file number 25 that become number 34, 
the value "name": "file #25", and the value "file": 25,
need to become : "name": "file #34", and the value "file": 34,

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: If you have a separate question it may be worth opening a new question with the errors you have not been able to overcome, including what you have tried. To change the content of a file, I would create a function that opens and changes the file based on the desired criteria, call the function in each iteration of the loop passing appropriate arguments. It is also possible to rename a file without needing to copy it by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the info, in this particular case I need to copy them. 

I’ll then create an other question regarding the part 2 of my project.

Comment: Hopefully you are able to find the resources to find the answer without needing to open a new question 

Comment: I’m searching everywhere and didn’t get it yet. I hope I will.